# Flac files play for only five seconds

Tags: 14.04, audacity, flac

Using Ubuntu 14.04. Flac files only play for five seconds in Audacity and moc, then skip to next file in playlist. Files seem to be intact.

I can't seem to find anything relevant on this issue.

Comment: Start audacity in command line with the song and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Interesting. Flac files that I have ripped on earlier versions of Ubuntu play without a problem. The problem is with new flac files that I have ripped in Ubuntu 14.04 using RipperX with the flac encoder.

Comment: Here is what audacity spits out from the command line:

Expression 'stream->playback.pcm' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4611

Answer (score 0):

the only way I can extract to flac the the mo is by using Sound Juicer. 
Ripper X only extracts the 1st 4 or 5 seconds as you say